# Multiple instances of CLLocationManager per application. Are they messing with each other?

Tags: ios, core-location, multiple-instances

Does one interfere other?

Eg. Using CoreMotion's `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical` you must turn location updates and it is OK to set `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;`

But in the same app I need location to have `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` and at that place I have another location manager.

Does one `desiredAccuracy` override other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should not override each other if they are separate instances of CLLocationManager.  Are you seeing differently?

Comment: Accutualy [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648948/ios-locationmanager-is-not-updating-location-titanium-appcelerator-module) is my real problem I see now.