# CLLocationManager is not updating location

Tags: ios5, gps, titanium, core-location, cllocationmanager

This is related to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648948/ios-locationmanager-is-not-updating-location-titanium-appcelerator-module) but I am openning a new one with iOS tags only because it could be that the problem is on native side.

Problem: location manager is not updating location. I tried reading `locationManager.location` and it always gives me one cached location.

Then I modified the code to use `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {}`
 is never being called.

my .h file:

```
#import "TiModule.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface TiMovementModule : TiModule<CLLocationManagerDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary *currentMovement;

- (void)startMovementUpdates:(id)args;
- (void)stopMovementUpdates:(id)args;

@end
```

.m

```
/**
 * Your Copyright Here
 *
 * Appcelerator Titanium is Copyright (c) 2009-2010 by Appcelerator, Inc.
 * and licensed under the Apache Public License (version 2)
 */
#import "TiMovementModule.h"
#import "TiBase.h"
#import "TiHost.h"
#import "TiUtils.h"

@interface  TiMovementModule ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) CMMotionManager *motionManager;

@end

@implementation TiMovementModule

@synthesize motionManager, locationManager;

#pragma mark Internal

// this is generated for your module, please do not change it
-(id)moduleGUID
{
    return @"3d2abdb6-bafb-451c-931d-a979dcc1ea78";
}

// this is generated for your module, please do not change it
-(NSString*)moduleId
{
    return @"ti.movement";
}

#pragma mark Lifecycle

-(void)startup
{
    // this method is called when the module is first loaded
    // you *must* call the superclass
    [super startup];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"[INFO] %@ loaded",self); //this prints
}

-(void)shutdown:(id)sender
{
    // this method is called when the module is being unloaded
    // typically this is during shutdown. make sure you don't do too
    // much processing here or the app will be quit forceably

    // you *must* call the superclass
    [super shutdown:sender];
}

#pragma mark Cleanup 

-(void)dealloc
{
    self.motionManager = nil;
    self.locationManager = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma Public APIs

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"I AM HEREEEEEE!!!!!!!"); //this never prints

}

- (void)startMovementUpdates:(id)args
{
    NSLog(@"[INFO] starting updates...");

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical];
    NSLog(@"[INFO] started updates."); //this prints
}

- (void)stopMovementUpdates:(id)args
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
}

- (id)currentMovement
{
    NSDictionary *location = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude], @"longitude",
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude], @"latitude",
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:locationManager.location.altitude], @"altitude",
                              nil];

    NSDictionary *rotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll], @"roll",
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch], @"pitch",
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw], @"yaw",
                              nil];


    NSDictionary *movementData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  location, @"location",
                                  rotation, @"rotation",
                                  nil];
    return movementData; // here I pull location and it always gives me cached location. 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that location updating has to be done from the main thread.
In Titanium you just have to call ENSURE_UI_THREAD at the function beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting a breakpoint on this line:

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

to see if you ever get there as there is no evidence from your code that it ever gets executed.